# What's the default language for a Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql

What is the default language used for `CREATE FUNCTION` in Postgres?

i.e., The language used if I don't specify one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no default.  Not specifying the language is an error.

```
create function adlsfjsdf() returns text as $$ sdlkj;djf;lskjdf;jasf $$;

ERROR:  no language specified
```

Comment: Interesting, at least it's explicit.